# how to find the view location in android

Tags: view, android-widget

How can I find the view position in android?

To get the position I used `view.getLeft()`, `view.getRight()`, `view.getTop()` and `view.getBottm()`. But these methods are returning `0` (Zero). I used these methods after calling the `setContentView()` method.

If anyone know the code to get the view position, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in 2.2:

```
custRegScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, activity.findViewById(labelId)
            .getTop() - (viewHeight / 2) + offset);
```

The bit of the code you're looking for is:

```
int viewPos = activity.findViewById(R.id.myView).getTop();
```

This should return the following spot in a view's "rectangle"

```
 >______
  |    |
  |    |
  |____|
```

I.e., the Y (vertical) coordinate of the top of the view.

Note that this is contextual based on what kind of Layout you're using.  This was tested in a ScrollView, as seen above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What specifically is not working?  Have you tried stepping through the code and seeing if the methods are returning proper values?  Is it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Where were you calling `getLeft()`, `getTop()`, etc?  A view's position isn't set until `onMeasure()` is called, and so those methods will return 0 until then.  `onCreate()` is called sometime before `onMeasure()`, and so calling `getLeft()` won't be much use in `onCreate()`.  You may want to move your code to `onMeasure()` or `onResume()`.  If you do override `onMeasure()`, however, be aware that it is usually called several times.